# How can I replace a Python 2.65 UCS-2 build with one built using UCS-4 without losing everything in my site-packages?

Tags: python, macos, unicode, python-2.6

I downloaded the Python 2.6.5 source, built it for OS 10.6.4 64-bit, and installed numerous dependencies. I opened a big project our team has been working on recently, ran the unit tests, and one of the tests failed because I had installed Python built using UCS-2 (I didn't know this was the default of OS X!)

**In a nutshell:**
I didn't supply flag `--enable-unicode=ucs4` when building Python.
(as I discovered was necessary: http://copia.posterous.com/confusion-over-python-storage-form-for-unicod)

Now I want to correct this without losing everything I put in site-packages.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Thank you!
Michaux

Comment: Just an FYI for anyone reading this question:

You will most likely need to rebuild numpy:
(Thanks Alex!)

Error: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PyUnicodeUCS2_FromUnicode
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so
  Expected in: dynamic lookup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save and restore `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages` (e.g. as a `.tar.bz2`), but the restored `.so`s will not work properly if any of their entry points deal with Python Unicode objects -- so, *those* packages (containing any such `.so` files) you'll have to rebuild/reinstall once your new Python version is working! Hopefully that's a far cry from "everything" you've put in site-packages (fingers crossed).

Comment: I'm feeling brave tonight. I think I'll try your suggestion; however, before I do: do you foresee any complications given that I rely upon the SciPy, Numpy, libsvm, bsddb3, MySQL_python-1.2.3, and pyodbc in my site-packages? (Also, I've set my PATH to use the Python I installed into /usr/local/lib)

Thanks again!

Comment: @mkelley, it depends -- do you care to send to any of those packages, or receive back from them, Unicode objects?  If so, then they'll have to be rebuilt -- but if you only send and receive byte strings (or non-string data), then I would not expect that.

Comment: Thank you. I do plan to send Unicode objects to them. I have more to learn about how and why the .so files are involved. For now, I'm willing to risk that I might have to re-install the aforementioned dependencies (I made sure to document "how" I got them built and installed in the first place!) Thank you!

Comment: @mkelley, you're welcome -- point is, if you send or receive unicode in UCS-4 to/from an extension (`.so`) built with UCS-2, you'll at least be passing or getting the wrong data (and perhaps risking a crash, though offhand I'm not sure about the latter point).